# How to call a function placed in another function with jQuery, without modifying the original code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is basically the framework of my code:

```
var firstfunction = function () {
    function innerfunction () {
        // Do stuff here
    }
}
```

How do I reference `innerfunction()`, without changing the code mentioned supra?

Comment: What do you mean by "*reference [it] by jQuery*"? What exactly do you want to do with it?

Comment: @David Good point, I removed that.

Comment: Shouldn't `firstfunction.innerfunction()` work? Checked and **NO** - leaving this here for reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to expose innerFunction as an API you could do the following:

```
var firstFunction = function () {
  var imPrivate = "foo"
  var innerFunction = function () {
    // do stuff
  }

  return {
    innerFunction : innerFunction
  }
}

firstFunction.innerFunction()
```

This would also let you create private methods, variables as well.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're wanting to make use of currying, this is a functional programming technique where you return an function from another function i.e.:

```
var f1 = function() {
    return function() {
    }
}

> f1()();
```